# iFrame inside Facebook Dialog Box

Tags: facebook, iframe, modal-dialog, dialog, fbdialogs

I am trying to open a flash gallery with modal box in my iFrame Facebook app, but it is bigger than 520px. I found 2 solutions:

1. Insert a piece of code in the parent windows to make the modal to open with Target `_parent`, This is **impossible** since the parent windows is the Facebook!
2. Open flash video with iFrame inside a Facebook Dialog Box,

I have been looking for a tutorial for days without success. Anyone knows how can I do something like this:

```
    <fb:dialog id="my_dialog">
    <fb:dialog-title>My title</fb:dialog-title> 
    <fb:dialog-content> Flash video </fb:dialog-content>
    </fb:dialog>
```

Maybe it's a solution for what I need, but it's more than 2 months and nobody answered this question.
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7427051/fbswf-not-working-in-fbdialog-box-shows-blank-white-space

Here is my page, but remember that it is a work in progress and I do not know how long it will be a useful link:
https://www.facebook.com/MegaPetBrasil?sk=app_244261928967214

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't try it out once but it might be because of fbml deprecated.. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

If it is wider than 520px , you can try canvas page (i know user will have to leave fan page) and integrate inside Facebook. It might be even better in user experience perspective, if i have been visiting your page and in tab app if you lock my Facebook screen and show a dialog box with flash gallery, i will annoyed. It will be much better in canvas without any popups. Guess.. :)

Comment: I include a link to my page in the question. Canvas page is my second option, 720px would be ideal for my project, but I'm trying to prevent the visitors from leaving the page every time they are watching the videos. I found several techniques in FBML, but it is a waste of time because in one month will no longer be supported.

Comment: At least for now, there isn't a solution that what you want to do in tab application. As you mentioned, you can't open dialog. You have to use Facebooks' but there is not suitable one for you. We have to obey platform limits basicly. Sorry..